# Package built by Poetry is missing runtime dependencies

Tags: python-packaging, requirements, python-poetry

I've been working on a project which so far has just involved building some cloud infrastructure, and now I'm trying to [add a CLI](https://github.com/linz/geostore/pull/1142) to simplify running some AWS Lambdas. Unfortunately both the sdist and wheel packages built using `poetry build` don't seem to include the dependencies, so I have to manually `pip install` all of them to run the command. Basically I

1. run `poetry build` in the project,
2. `cd "$(mktemp --directory)"`,
3. `python -m venv .venv`,
4. `. .venv/bin/activate`,
5. `pip install /path/to/result/of/poetry/build/above`, and then
6. run the new .venv/bin/ executable.

At this point the executable fails, because `pip` did not install any of the package dependencies. *If I `pip show PACKAGE` the `Requires` line is empty.*

The Poetry manual doesn't seem to specify how to link dependencies to the built package, so what do I have to do instead?

I am using some optional dependencies, could that be interfering with the build process? To be clear, even non-optional dependencies do not show up in the [package](https://github.com/linz/geostore/suites/4248835463/artifacts/110229472) dependencies.

pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.black]
line-length = 100

[tool.coverage.report]
exclude_lines = [
    'if TYPE_CHECKING:',
    'if __name__ == "__main__":',
    'pragma: no cover',
]
fail_under = 100

[tool.coverage.run]
branch = true
omit = [
    ".venv/*",
]

[tool.isort]
case_sensitive = true
line_length = 100
profile = "black"

[tool.mypy]
show_error_codes = true
strict = true

[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = [
    "jsonschema",
    "jsonschema._utils",
    "jsonschema.validators",
    "multihash",
    "pystac",
    "pystac.layout",
    "pytest_subtests",
    "smart_open",
    "linz_logger"
]
ignore_missing_imports = true

[tool.poetry]
name = "geostore"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Central storage, management and access for important geospatial datasets developed by LINZ"
authors = [
    "Bill M. Nelson <bmnelson@linz.govt.nz>",
    "Daniel Silk <dsilk@linz.govt.nz>",
    "Ivan Mincik <ivan.mincik@gmail.com>",
    "Mitchell Paff <mpaff@linz.govt.nz>",
    "Sandro Santilli <strk@kbt.io>",
    "Simon Planzer <splanzer@linz.govt.nz>",
    "Victor Engmark <vengmark@linz.govt.nz>",
]
license = "MIT"
readme = "README.md"
homepage = "https://github.com/linz/geostore"
repository = "https://github.com/linz/geostore"
keywords = [
    "SpatioTemporal Asset Catalog (STAC)",
    "Toitū Te Whenua Land Information New Zealand",
]
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
    "Environment :: Console",
    "Framework :: AWS CDK",
    "Framework :: Pytest",
    "Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop",
    "Intended Audience :: Information Technology",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Natural Language :: English",
    "Operating System :: POSIX",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    "Topic :: Communications :: File Sharing",
    "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS",
    "Topic :: Utilities",
    "Typing :: Typed",
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
"aws-cdk.aws-dynamodb" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-ec2" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-ecr" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-ecr_assets" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-ecs" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-events" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-events-targets" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-iam" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-lambda" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-lambda-event-sources" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-lambda-python" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-s3" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-sns" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions" = {version = "*", optional = true}
"aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions_tasks" = {version = "*", optional = true}
awscli = {version = "*", optional = true}
boto3 = "*"
cattrs = {version = "*", optional = true}
jsonschema = {version = "*", extras = ["format"], optional = true}
multihash = {version = "*", optional = true}
pynamodb = {version = "*", optional = true}
pystac = {version = "*", optional = true}
slack-sdk = {version = "*", extras = ["models", "webhook"], optional = true}
smart-open = {version = "*", extras = ["s3"], optional = true}
strict-rfc3339 = {optional = true, version = "*"}
typer = "*"
ulid-py = {version = "*", optional = true}
linz-logger = {version = "*", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = "*"
boto3-stubs = {version = "*", extras = ["batch", "dynamodb", "events", "lambda", "lambda-python", "s3", "s3control", "sns", "sqs", "ssm", "stepfunctions", "sts"]}
gitlint = "*"
ipdb = "*"
isort = "*"
language-formatters-pre-commit-hooks = "*"
mutmut = "*"
mypy = "*"
pre-commit = "*"
pylint = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-randomly = "*"
pytest-socket = "*"
pytest-subtests = "*"
pytest-timeout = "*"
types-pkg-resources = "*"
types-python-dateutil = "*"
types-requests = "*"
types-six = "*"
types-toml = "*"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies.coverage]
version = "*"
extras = ["toml"]

[tool.poetry.extras]
cdk = [
    "aws-cdk.aws-dynamodb",
    "aws-cdk.aws-ec2",
    "aws-cdk.aws-ecr",
    "aws-cdk.aws-ecr_assets",
    "aws-cdk.aws-ecs",
    "aws-cdk.aws-events",
    "aws-cdk.aws-events-targets",
    "aws-cdk.aws-iam",
    "aws-cdk.aws-lambda",
    "aws-cdk.aws-lambda-event-sources",
    "aws-cdk.aws-lambda-python",
    "aws-cdk.aws-s3",
    "aws-cdk.aws-sns",
    "aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions",
    "aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions_tasks",
    "awscli",
    "cattrs",
]
check_files_checksums = [
    "boto3",
    "linz-logger",
    "multihash",
    "pynamodb",
]
check_stac_metadata = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "strict-rfc3339",
]
cli = [
    "boto3",
    "typer",
]
content_iterator = [
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
]
datasets = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "pystac",
    "ulid-py",
]
dataset_versions = [
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "ulid-py",
]
import_asset_file = [
    "boto3",
    "linz-logger",
    "smart-open",
]
import_dataset = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "smart-open",
    "ulid-py",
]
import_metadata_file = [
    "boto3",
    "linz-logger",
]
import_status = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
]
notify_status_update = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "slack-sdk"
]
populate_catalog = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pystac",
]
update_dataset_catalog = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
    "ulid-py"
]
upload_status = [
    "boto3",
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
]
validation_summary = [
    "jsonschema",
    "linz-logger",
    "pynamodb",
]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
geostore = "geostore.cli:app"

[tool.pylint.MASTER]
disable = [
    "duplicate-code",
    "missing-class-docstring",
    "missing-function-docstring",
    "missing-module-docstring",
]
load-plugins = [
    "pylint.extensions.mccabe",
]
max-complexity = 6

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--randomly-dont-reset-seed"
markers = [
    "infrastructure: requires a deployed infrastructure",
]
python_functions = "should_*"
testpaths = [
    "tests"
]
```

As you can see the boto3 and typer runtime dependencies are not optional, so I'd expect to see them in `poetry show geostore`.

Comment: when you say "include dependencies", do you mean that you expect the build artifact to literally include them? or do you mean that if you pip-install your resulting wheel, that pip will resolve and download all missing dependencies?

Comment: For the latter, if you added your dependencies via `poetry add my-runtime-dependency` to the `pyproject.toml` file, your build artifacts should tell an installer about them, which can then in turn try to figure out how to supply it. For the former, poetry doesn't support it out of the box. Other tools do, though.

Comment: Show the `pyproject.toml` if possible.

Comment: @sinoroc I've posted the file; unfortunately it's pretty big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Poetry. Or at least it's not clear from the documentation what the expected behavior would be in a case such as yours.

In your `pyproject.toml`, you specify two dependencies as required in this section:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
…
awscli = {version = "*", optional = true}
boto3 = "*"
…
typer = "*"
…
```

So, as opposed to `awscli` among many others, `boto3` and `typer` should be required because the `optional` attribute is not set and defaults to `false`. But you also list the two required dependencies as "extras" in this section:

```
[tool.poetry.extras]
…
cli = [
    "boto3",
    "typer",
]
…
```

Poetry takes that to mean that they are in fact optional, not required. Which makes sense, in a way, because extras are effectively optional. If you inspect the `.whl` wheel file built by Poetry (it's just a zip archive), specifically the `METADATA` file in it (which is what Pip refers to when installing the package), then it contains this line:

```
Requires-Dist: typer; extra == "cli"
```

So that dependency is in fact optional: It will only get installed if users ask for it explicitly with `pip install geostore[cli]`.

The solution then is simple: Remove all references to the required dependencies from the `extras` section. They are not needed there anyway.

The Poetry documentation is in fact not very clear on what `optional` really signifies. That attribute is (currently) only briefly mentioned in the [section on the `pyproject.toml` file](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras). One could also argue that if `optional` is `false`, then the `extras` section should not override that value.

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation! Yeah, they were both part of an extra because every runtime dependency *should* be optional, only included via extras. We settled on this approach because it seems to be the "least bad" way to have a [single repo combining](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2270) AWS CDK infrastructure code, Lambdas and a CLI, all of which have different dependencies. I guess this means we're going to have to install boto3 and typer in a bunch of places they are not needed, or completely rearchitect the repo. :(